# Entity Framework - BulkInsertExtension

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bulkinsert

I was trying to do a bulk insert in EF using the bulkinsert extensions DLL from this link https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/. But i always get the error Value is Null.

```
using (var ctx= new context)
{
    list<tbldummy> lstdummy= new list<tbldummy>();
    for(int i =0;i<=1000;i++)
         {
          lstdummy.Add(//object of type tbldummy);
         }
ctx.bulkinsert(lstdummy);  //crash in this line "Value cannot be null"
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in the code where you have `//object of type tbldummy`. You have a null field that is specified not null in the SQL schema. Show us the table definition and the code you use to make your objects for us to help you fix your problem.

Comment: i have check that also. there are only two fields and both have value assigned and in the sql schema there is not constraint on the table also

Comment: Well, then I guess your program is working fine and you have no incorrect assumptions about what you are doing which you think is correct but in reality is causing your program to crash. I mean you "checked it", why would we need to look at it.

Comment: because my code is crashing

Comment: Did you try putting only one object in your lstdummy collection? instead of 1000 ... your code seems to be fine, so mostly it is a data-related issue.

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: No i did not get a chance to look into the issue

Comment: It here anything special in tbldummy? You should add the class code to your question. This library doesn't support all kind of inheritance and associations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to avoid **private** classes that derive from model classes that are mapped to a table in your database. I got this exception because I had EF adding additional columns to a table because of a private subclass. BulkInsert does not seem to handle these additional columns through a private subclass well.

In my case I got an `InvalidOperationException` on every call to BulkInsert, even though I was inserting stuff in an unrelated table.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

lstdummy.Add(new object of type bldummy)

Comment: there are no mistakes on the provided code then. It might have to work can you provide the whole code, I mean with the lstdummy.Add("") statement too